# Convert a single character to lowercase

Tags: python

Instructions:
The first step is to write a function lowerChar(char) that can return the result of converting a single character char to lower case. It should do the following:

> if the input character char is a capital letter (between 'A' and 'Z'),
>   it should return the lower-case version of the letter (between 'a' and
>   'z'). In all other cases, it should return the same char which was
>   input.

(In order to do the first step, you will have to use an if statement, an and operator, and apply some knowledge from the lesson about strings.)

all I have is -

```
def lowerChar(char):
```

Comment: If that's all you have, then you don't have anything at all except an assignment.

Answer (score 6):

```
In [26]: 'A'.lower()
Out[26]: 'a'

In [27]: 'a'.lower()
Out[27]: 'a'
```

So what you're after is this:

```
def lowerChar(char):
  return char.lower()
```

Alternatively, you could futz around with the ascii values like this:

```
def lowerChar(char):
  if 97 <= ord(char) <= 122: # lower case
    return char
  elif 65 <= ord(char) <= 90: # upper case
    return chr(ord(char)-32)
  else: # not a letter of the alphabet
    return char
```

Comment: Considering this is obviously some assignment to learn programming basics, I don't think you're really expected to use such an easy way out of the problem. It's like having someone told to write a string class and then just subclassing the string class coming with the compiler. :)

Comment: @Mario: I'm updating with `ord` and `chr` as we speak

Comment: While at it, you should probably make it step by step, because the way the hints are written, this might help understanding the whole process.

Comment: @Mario: I never write step by step code for homework questions. It would negate the purpose of homework. I don't mind giving high level answers that OP can write the steps to themselves - that would force them to understand the solution.

Comment: Well, it always depends on the individual I guess. Having complete code that doesn't explain anything might be as bad as exact step by step stuff you just skim through.

Comment: @Mario: perhaps. But when it comes to homework, I'd rather give unhelpful working code, than simple, fully explained code (which is far easier to plagiarize)

Answer (score 2):

Nicer not to have hard coded constants

```
def lowerChar(c):
    if 'A' <= c <= 'Z':
        return chr(ord(c) - ord('A') + ord('a'))
    else:
        return c
```

another way without `chr` and `ord`

```
from string import ascii_lowercase, ascii_uppercase
def lowerChar(c):
    if 'A' <= c <= 'Z':
        return ascii_lowercase[ascii_uppercase.index(c)]
    else:
        return c
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def lowerChar(char):
    if len(char) != 1 or not isinstance(char, basestring):
        raise TypeError
    if char >= 'A' and char <= 'Z':
        return char.lower()
    else:
        return char
```

The second and third lines are optional, and just ensure that the passed-in values is actually a single-character string, not a multi-character string.

Comment: This doesn't constrict the letters to just '(between A to Z)' - Uppercase letters like `Æ` would still be converted to lower using this implementation.

Comment: `if len(char) != 0 or not isinstance(char, basestring):` Shouldn't that 0 be a 1?

Comment: @SamyBencherif Yes it should! Thanks for catching that.

Comment: @TobiasRoland I've switched to testing that it's only A-Z. Though I think this correction may make this answer a bit of a Monkey's Paw.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a nice easy way to do it:

```
import string

def lowerChar(char):
    if char in string.ascii_uppercase:
        return char.lower()
    else:
        return char
```

**Explanation**
So basically, you're checking if the character **is in** the uppercase values of the [ASCII-table](http://www.asciitable.com/) - if it is, then you return the lower case version of the char. If not, you simply return the char "as-is".

Comment: Doing the test and then just calling `c.lower()` sounds a bit obsolete. Either do the check and then a manual transformation or just pass the result of `c.lower()`.

Comment: The problem with *not* checking if the string is in the uppercase values of the ASCII-table is that non-english letters such as Ö, Æ, Å or Ø would still be converted to lowercase - if the answer is to be read literally, only characters between A and Z are to be converted.

Comment: Point taken, although I'd guess such basic tasks won't even try to explain codepages or any other extended stuff. ;)

Comment: There isn't any variable or constant `c`. Was that supposed to `char`?

Comment: Oh my. Yes it was - I've updated my answer. I'm so used to just writing 'c' whenever I'm using a char as my variable, since 'char' is quite often a reserved keyword.